# before_destroy in rails, little help need!

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have table called `users`, if i want to delete some `user` (User can add `questions` and add `respondents` (who will `answer` on his `questions`)), i need to delete him and get his id to people who deleted this person. So for example:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
def destroy_and_transfer_to(user)
  transaction do
    questions.each do |q|
      q.update_attribute(:user_id => user)
    end
    respondents.each do |r|
      r.update_attribute(:user_id => user)
    end
    destroy
  end
end
```

Now use this method instead of the "destroy" method.
OR
you can stick to callbacks like this

```
before_destroy :transfer_to
attr_accessor :user_who_takes_over

private

def transfer_to
  if user_who_takes_over
    questions.each do |q|
      q.update_attribute(:user_id => user_who_takes_over)
    end
    respondents.each do |r|
      r.update_attribute(:user_id => user_who_takes_over)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can :

```
@user.user_who_takes_over = current_user
@user.destroy
```

Just a couple of ideas! Good Luck!

Update: All the code i provided above belongs in your model.
In your controller you need to have a destroy method

in your controller

```
def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.user_who_takes_over = current_user
  if user.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "User destroyed, all stuff transferred"
  else
    Rails.logger.debug(user.errors.inspect)
    flash[:error] = "Error destroying user"
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Change to suite your need of course!

Comment: thaaanks for quick response, but something wrong and doest work for me :( i using first example and notginh , and use second and still nothing, wait, second examle i shoudl write in model or controller?

Comment: look what i have =>  ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to destroy. Actions: check_if_authenticated, create, destroy_and_transfer_to, index, and update):

Comment: Big thanks that you are helping, wasting your time, but i still have errors, when i writing this all I get =>   User Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 57) 
  User Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = '--- :id\n') when i using second method where before_destroy

Comment: I'm assuming you know a bit of rails! no worries. here to help.

Comment: try user = User.find(params[:id])

Comment: sorry, i;m not a pro as you are. so i'm just learning, i wrote that you are gave me, but still nothing I get this => NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<UsersController:0x7f8300726b88>):
mby insted of current_user i should user something like that -> "session[:user].id" ? And with my models (relations) everything are okei? hmm, strange problem...

Comment: sure try that session[:user].id if thats what give you the id .. dont just copy the code i've written. try to understand the essence of it. the meansing of it.

Comment: okei, yes, i'm trying to understand, some I do, some dont, if I using first example, i should use transaction? or i can delete this? and questions = Question.find(:all) should write to find any questions and respondends?

Comment: transaction is necessary in the first example as it's not provided by rails in our own custom method. You do not need to do anything to fetch questions. "questions" in an instance method is going to basically be "self.questions" which is basically finds all questions of the user instance. (bascially user 66's questions). You can use the power of "associations". You dont need to do Question.find(:all) :)